# jquery chosen plugin with collection select in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins, ruby-on-rails-4

```
 <%= f.label "SELECT MODEL LOCATION *" %><br />
      <div class="list_number">1</div><%= f.collection_select :location_id, Location.all, :id, :name, prompt: true, :required => true,  :class => 'chosen-select' %>

      <%= f.label "SELECT YOUR MODEL *" %><br />
      <div class="list_number">2</div>
      <%= f.grouped_collection_select :performer_id, Location.order(:name), :performers, :name, :id, :first_name, include_blank: true, :required => true,  class: 'chosen-select' %>

      <%= f.label "SELECT YOUR CATEGORY *" %><br />
      <div class="list_number">3</div>
    <%= f.select :clip_category_id, grouped_options_for_select(Performer.order(:first_name).map{ |group| [group.first_name, group.clip_category_performers.map{ |c| [c.clip_category.name, c.clip_category.id, {'data-amount'=>c.amount}] } ] }), include_blank: true, required: true, class: 'chosen-select' %>
```

I have used this collection select and as you see I have used chosen select Jquery plugin using chosen-rails gem. I am not able to make collection-select work. I am not able to set class for the collection select even though I have given here in the code when I inspect using inspect element in browser it won't show any class. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `grouped_collection_select(method, collection, group_method, group_label_method, option_key_method, option_value_method, options = {}, html_options = {})` count your arguments the one you don't need you still need to pass in `nil`. I'm not sure if `include_blank: true, :required => true` are option or html option, if they are option you may need to wrap them in a hash. I thought the new Ruby named parameters suppose to fix this…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to split the rails select options and the html options more explicitly. I've also found that sometimes you can just chain all options however you want and sometimes you need to split the options in two hashes. See the documentation for details:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_collection_select

Now try something more like this (note the hash brackets for the select options and html options):

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :performer_id, Location.order(:name), :performers, :name, :id, :first_name, { include_blank: true, :required => true },  { class: 'chosen-select' } %>
```

Also, you could switch from the outdated Chosen plugin, which is no longer under active development to Select2. It is based on Chosen and offers a lot more functionality and improvements. http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/index.html

Chosen is most probably not responsible for your problems though, so you should do the switch after dealing with the class issue first.